# Move constructor doesn't get fired

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Why in this class move constructor doesn't get fired?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using std::cout;
template<class T>
class Movable
{
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer_type = T*;
    const std::size_t init_size_{ 1 };
    std::size_t current_size_{ init_size_ };
    const value_type init_value_{ 0 };
    pointer_type data_ = new value_type[init_size_]{init_value_};
public:
    Movable();
    Movable(Movable&&);
    virtual ~Movable();

};

   template<class T>
Movable<T>::Movable(Movable&& dead_meat)
{
    data_ = dead_meat.data_;
    current_size_ = dead_meat.current_size_;
    dead_meat.data_ = nullptr;
    dead_meat.current_size_ = 0;
    cout << "Move ctor";
}
template<class T>
Movable<T>::Movable()
{
    cout << "dflt ctor\n";
}
```

and in main:

```
#include "Movable.hpp"

int main()
{
    auto m_var{ Movable<int>{} };
    return 0;
}
```

What happens is, only the default constructor is being fired off. Would be really greatful for some explanation on why and how to make it happen.

Comment: Has you checked if the copy constructor is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completely independent of copies and moves, initialisation like that is permitted to *completely elide either*. That means the object is constructed in place. It's a sort of standard-permitted "optimisation".

Comment: That's exactly what I meant! ;)